# Animating UIView and its sub layers

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, calayer

I have a subclassed `UIView` that is comprised of several layers (mostly `CAShapeLayers` with a few `CATextLayers`). The problem I have is that if I animate resizing the `UIView` using an **animation block** (`beginAnimations`, `commitAnimations`) and relayout the sublayers in the **overridden `layoutSubviews`**, then the layers are not animated with the `UIView`.

Below is my code to animate the frame of the `UIView`:

```
miniView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:MAXFLOAT];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

miniView.frame = newFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

So the problem is that the view is properly animated but the sublayers are not. I can see the view growing and shrinking but the sublayers grow immediately and then stay the new larger size. What is the best way to resize the sublayers of a view when the view is resized? And how do I make those animate in the same way with the parent view?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same issue as you did Noah. The solution provided by Brandon is slightly different since its just scaling the sublayers as part of the layer instead of actually redrawing them at their new size during the animation.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see more code to really fix the problem, however you can try to animate miniView's layer instead of its view.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"]; 
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
// additional setup...

[miniView.layer layoutIfNeeded];
[miniView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"whateverYouWant"];
```

Instead of using UIKit animation this should be more flexible once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I had similar problem. This post gave me the hint. UIView animations only work on UIKit view's etc.. If you want to animate CALayer objects, you need to do so using the CoreAnimation API and not the UIView animate... methods.